# Missing Reference Exception Photon Pun

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, real-time-multiplayer, photon-pun

I am Working on an multiplayer fps game the code throws an missing reference exception in the line given below the error doesn't show up when there is only one player in the room but it starts coming as soon as another player joins the room

```
private IEnumerator Shoot()
    {
        ammoLeft -= 1;

        animator.SetBool("fire", true);

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(playerCam.position, playerCam.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            //Missing Reference Expection The transform you are accessing is destroyed
            //code works in singleplayer
            if (hit.transform.tag == "Player" && hit.transform != null)
            {
                HealthManager HealthScript = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<HealthManager>();

                if (HealthScript != null)
                {
                    HealthScript.TakeDamage(damage);
                }
            }

        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);

        animator.SetBool("fire", false);

        if (ammoLeft <= 0f)
        {
            StartCoroutine("Reload");
        }
```

Error in this line

```
Physics.Raycast(playerCam.position, playerCam.forward, out hit, range)
```

I have checked if my camera is null but the problem doesn't fix so I am clueless

```
 private void Awake()
    {
        if (!pv.IsMine)
        {
            Destroy(ui);
        }

        if (playerCam == null)
        {
            playerCam = FindObjectOfType<Camera>().transform;
        }

        ammoLeft = magazineSize;
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
```

Inspector Window

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc69B.png
```

Comment: I can only guess that either `if (!pv.IsMine) { Destroy(ui); }` includes destroying the camera or `FindObjectOfType<Camera>()` maybe returns the wrong camera (which later is destroyed) .. in general I would check what is running that coroutine .. sounds like either way it should only be executed by the local player but maybe is also executed by the remote players?

Comment: Oh I was using the other player's Camera which is destroyed since my code destroys any camera which doesn't belongs to the local player

Thanks